# Perguntas temporais e amplas

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-duplicadas, perguntas-fechadas

Eu fiz uma pergunta a algumas semanas sobre licenças de software, [Quais são as licenças de software adotadas atualmente, e qual seu uso mais indicado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69051/8039), e de certa forma intencionalmente abri o leque da pergunta para que fosse respondido de forma ampla abrangendo no momento em que temos de licença em nosso contexto da língua portuguesa.

Mas exatamente por isso a pergunta foi fechada, caracterizada como falei com muito ampla e temporal.

Mas a dois dias desta postagem no meta, foi feita outra pergunta que está neste link [Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76564/8039), a pergunta está em formato diferente, e talvez está mais ampla, até mesmo porque envolve dois assuntos, o funcionamento das licenças e o que é um software livre.

Da minha parte achei até uma iniciativa muito boa da parte do advogado, já que ele mesmo respondeu e contribuiu de uma forma que acredito ser muito positiva, porém sua pergunta de certa forma é uma duplicada, mais ampla ainda do que fiz.

Comment: Delfino a única diferença que vejo é que ele faz perguntas especificas.

Comment: Aqui está um bom exemplo de que a forma como se pergunta pode fazer toda a diferença.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi a questão.

Comment: @Delfino, acho que a maior diferença foi que postei como wiki da comunidade... Btw, dá uma olhada no link do primeiro parágrafo (fora o aviso)... foi justamente a tentativa de responder sua pergunta que me fez escrever o wiki...

Comment: Existem diferenças entre elas que fazem a segunda ser mais fácil de aceitar, apesar de ser ampla. Além de ser menos temporal, ter uma resposta imediata e ainda mais sendo wiki ajuda. Respostas boas salvam perguntas. No mundo perfeito não deveria acontecer isto mas é difícil ter certeza. A do Delfino teria grande chance de gerar respostas ruins, embora desse para responder. Eu acho que muitas perguntas ao invés de fechar poderiam ser limitadas para usuários experientes ou que a resposta fosse aprovada por usuários experientes, tal qual é feito com edições. Isto salvaria muitas perguntas.

Comment: Uma visão muito interessante  @bigown, como sempre.

Comment: Delfino, por ora eu alterei o motivo de fechamento da sua pergunta, marquei como duplicata da outra. Dependendo de como o debate evoluir aqui no meta, podemos rever isso. Minha intenção foi facilitar o acesso ao conteúdo que está na resposta da outra pergunta, deixando claro para quem chegar na sua que tem conteúdo sobre o assunto no link. Aliás, essa é a principal função da marcação de duplicatas no site: sinalizar que a resposta pode ser encontrada em outra pergunta (caso contrário, poderíamos simplesmente excluir as duplicatas, em vez de fechar).

Comment: @bigown Interessante mesmo a sua ideia. Se tiver condições, daria um bom feature-request. Fiquei pensando como isso poderia funcionar na prática, talvez um debate separado aqui no meta seja um bom caminho para pensar coletivamente nos detalhes.

Comment: mas se formos mesmo avaliar, tudo é "temporal"...

Comment: Sem dúvida @DanielOmine, às perguntas e respostas são válidas enquanto úteis aquilo que existe, se aplica e se usa.